# Angular Geolocation service returns nothing

Tags: angularjs, geolocation

I am trying to use the following geolocation service in my angular project to get location.
service file :

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('geolocation', function ($q, $http) {
    var getLocation = function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            // If supported and have permission for location...
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                // 
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                    var result = {latitude : position.coords.latitude , longitude : position.coords.longitude}
                    // Adding randomization since we are all in the same location...
                    result.latitude += (Math.random() >0.5? -Math.random()/100 : Math.random()/100  );
                    result.longitude += (Math.random() >0.5? -Math.random()/100 : Math.random()/100  );
                    getNearbyCity(result.latitude, result.longitude).then(function(data){
                        result.address = data.data.results[1].formatted_address;
                        defer.resolve(result);
                    });
                }, function(error){
                    defer.reject({message: error.message, code:error.code});
                });
            }
            else {
                defer.reject({error: 'Geolocation not supported'});
            }
            return defer.promise;
        }
        var getNearbyCity = function (latitude, longitude){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude +',' + longitude +'&sensor=true';
            $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                     defer.resolve({data : data});
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  defer.reject({error: 'City not found'});
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
        var service = {
            getLocation : getLocation,
            getNearbyCity: getNearbyCity
        };
        return service;
  });
```

And I call it in my controller :

```
    angular.module('myApp')

          .controller('HomeCtrl',  function ($scope, geolocation) {


             geolocation.getLocation().then(function(result){
                $scope.location = result;
                console.log($scope.location);
             });
});
```

Unfortunately the console.log() returns nothing.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your code, change the request to:

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude +',' + longitude +'&sensor=true';
```

Working [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ezXP93oD9uEsn5r1pfO1?p=preview)

Comment: I changed the url, it doesn't work.  And your plunker doesn't work

Comment: It does work! you need to click the button, now i have changed it to ng-init, check

Comment: This works well in my windows computer. But not in Linux. I will check to see what the heck is going on. I appreciate your effort. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error that a location was undefined. After experimenting with various async functions and repositioning the return statements, I found that the problem was much more ridiculous:

The location services on my mac were turned off.

Firefox wasn't giving me any notification of it, but when I tested on Chrome, a popup recommended that I 'open settings and turn on location services'.

Just thought I would mention in case it saves anyone some headache.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
  $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+pos.coords.latitude+','+pos.coords.longitude+'&sensor=true').then(function(res){
    console.log(res.data);
  });
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.